# Training multiple models: ValueError: Variable hidden1/kernel already exists, disallowed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am doing hyperparameter search:

```
for layer1_filters, layer1_kernels \
    in product(layer1_filters_list,layer1_kernels_list):
  cm = CifarModel()
  cm.build_train_validate_model(layer1_filters, layer1_kernels)
```

where `build_train_validate_model` defines the layers:

```
self.hidden1 = tf.layers.conv2d(self.input_layer, layer1_filters,
        layer1_kernels, activation=activation, name='hidden1')
```

On the 2nd iteration of the hyperparameter search loop when the 2nd candidate model is defined I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: Variable hidden1/kernel already exists, disallowed.
Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?
```

I find this confusing because each iteration of the hyperparameter loop creates its own model object in the line `cm = CifarModel()` and therefore there should be no name conflict between multiple invocations of `self.hidden1 = tf.layers.conv2d` in different iteration of the hyperparameter search loop. Thus the question: why does TF claim the name conflict between members of different objects of the same class?

Moreover, after I added

```
tf.AUTO_REUSE = True
```

before the hyperparameter search loop the problem persisted.

---

Here's the graph definition code:

```
# Build the model
self.flat_features, self.flat_label = self.iterator.get_next()
self.input_layer = self.flat_features
self.hidden1 = tf.layers.conv2d(self.input_layer, layer1_filters,
        layer1_kernels, activation=activation)
self.normal1 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(self.hidden1)
self.hidden2 = tf.layers.conv2d(self.normal1, layer2_filters,
        layer2_kernels, activation=activation)
self.normal2 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(self.hidden2)
self.maxpool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(self.normal2,
        (maxpool1_stride,maxpool1_stride), (maxpool1_stride,maxpool1_stride))
self.hidden3 = tf.layers.conv2d(self.maxpool1, layer3_filters,
        layer3_kernels, activation=activation)
self.maxpool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(self.hidden3,
        (self.drop3.shape[1],self.drop3.shape[1]), (self.drop3.shape[1],self.drop3.shape[1]) )
self.flat = tf.layers.flatten(self.maxpool2)
self.logits = tf.layers.dense(self.flat, len(self.label_names))
```

Comment: Can you post the entire code where you are creating the graph?

Comment: [This link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2975) could be helpful - "I suspect the problem is that you're rebuilding the graph". Or just try `tf.reset_default_graph()` before each hyperparam search loop iteration - but for now it's unclear what's the problem and how to fix this issue. You should add more code to your example; especially `CifarModel` code